# Can someone wait before patenting something?

Tags: patents

Let's say I invent something.

I manufacture it without patenting it.

30 years later, someone reverse-engineered my invention.

I see that he is a few months away from manufacturing it, can I rush in and patent it now?

Comment: Under the patent laws of which country? Please add a tag.

Answer (score 4):

### No

A patent application must be lodged *before* the invention is made public in any way (or, in the US, within 1 year of the public disclosure).

Comment: This is not universally true.  For instance, under US law, you may apply for a patent up to one year after publicly disclosing the invention.  [35 USC 102 (b) (1)](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/35/102).  Though certainly the 30 years in the question would be much too long.